# (RoR) Styles still applied even though I moved them to a different controller's unique CSS file?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on Rails app, I have a blog controller and a sites controller. The styles are all found in the sites.css file (which is supposed to apply only to the sites controller) yet they are being displayed on the blog controller view as well. If you want to see the page you can go to maxpleaner.heroku.com (everything except the blog page looks fine - besides the navbar, there should be no styles at all on the blog page).

You can check out the source code at github.com/maxpleaner/homepage.

Basically the thing to notice in the source code is that the css code is in app/assets/stylesheets/sites.css.scss, so why are they applying to the blog page, which is found in the blog controller?

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245228/how-do-i-use-controller-specific-stylesheets-in-rails-3-2-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, all your style sheets will be merged into the application.css. if your application.css looks like:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

The require_tree directive in a CSS manifest will require all stylesheets from the current directory

```
 *=require_tree .
```

You can require a specific stylesheet named (sites) with:

```
*= require sites
```

you can specify individual files and they are compiled in the order specified. For example, you might concatenate three CSS files together this way:

```
/* ...
*= require reset
*= require layout
*= require chrome
*/
```

Refer this for detailed information. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

If you want to include a directory named custom, which contains CSS files then specify it as below in application.css

```
*= require_tree ./custom
```

Comment: so what do I put? I don't understand what to do once I've removed `*= require_tree`

Comment: remove the line which has *= require_tree .  and now include only css u want. example, if you want only two css files named sites and homes, then add only that *= require sites  (next line) *= require homes

Comment: i updated answer, and also included reference link for detailed info on how to accomplish this.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I am still a bit confused. If I want sites.css to only apply to "Sites" views, should I (1) remove `require tree .` from application.html.erb and (2) add `require sites` to  application.html.erb?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your `application.css` file, this line is there

```
*= require_tree .
```

which loads all the stylesheet files, remove this line and load page specific stylesheets

Comment: so what do I put? I don't understand what to do once I've removed `*= require_tree`

Answer (score 0):

By default all scss and css files are compiled into one application.css file. They are separated just for convenience into separate files. This like most things in Rails can however be changed quite easily. Take a look at your application.css manifest file.