# Rails scss stylesheet per action

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

How can I render a stylesheet per action in rails?

Since my app is not the standart CRUD app, my controllers end up with a few custom routes which require very different CSS's.

So, I'm wondering, is there any way to load the css on a per action basis but still take advantage of the asset pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

create a directory for each of your controllers inside stylesheets directory and create css files corresponding to your action, then put this in you layout file

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}" %>
```

Comment: With this I believe we're not taking advantage of rails asset pipeline. I've found this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/a/22915786/2517796 here on SO and I believe this is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use controller specific assets. Just remove the `*= require_tree .` from application.css. And include the stylesheet the action specific stylesheet in its view by `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style.css" %>` but you have to tell rails to compile them by `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = ["style.css"]`. You can read more about it [here](http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/). This way I guess we are using rails assets pipelines just not in default way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique id to the body based on the controller path and action:

Helper:

```
  def page_id
    "#{controller_path.tr('/', '-')}-#{action_name}".dasherize
  end
```

Layout:

```
<body id="<%= page_id %>"...
```

Then scope your styles to it:

/users/index.scss

```
#users-index {
  .. page specific styles here ..
}
```