# different css for index action in rails 5 bootstrap 4 (single controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4

I am using a specific bootstrap 4 template for my application. This template (cover.css) is specific to the homepage as all the others pages will use a different style.

How can I use `cover.css` only for the index action?

In my application.css I added `@import "cover"` can I have this only applied to the index action?

I tried creating two layouts instead: `application.html.erb` to use it for the application, and a second layout `home.html.erb` just for the home page. How can I associate `cover.css` for only the `index` action and have my dashboard layout and css for the rest of the application?

I am using rails 5 and bootstrap 4 alpha.

Comment: What's the controller name for the home page?

Comment: it is the same controller for the whole application. I do not have a separate controller for the home page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails scss stylesheet per action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022991/rails-scss-stylesheet-per-action)

Comment: not exactly @slowjack2k. The question linked refers to a case with multiple controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

You can create a layout which includes the cover.css asset, and then only apply the layout for the index action as described here [Rails layouts per action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025784/rails-layouts-per-action)

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :resolve_layout

  # ...

  private

  def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when "new", "create"
      "some_layout"
    when "index"
      "other_layout"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

Another option would be to use a single layout and scope your styles.

In `views/layouts/application.html.erb` Set classes on the body tag like this

`<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">` 
When rendered it will output 
`<body class="home index">`

Then in your cover.css scope your styles to the `.home.index` selector

```
body.home.index h1{
    /* this style is only applied on the home/index page */
}
```

Comment: which of these options do you think is more of a best practices kind of solution?

Comment: Both of them are acceptable as best practices. You could use both solutions together. In this case, if it's only CSS that you need to be different, then I would say just scope the styles. If you need the layout to be entirely different, then of course use the resolve layout method.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

See the 3rd answer here: [How do I use Controller specific stylesheets in Rails 3.2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245228/how-do-i-use-controller-specific-stylesheets-in-rails-3-2-1/22915786#22915786)