# What is the best way to add a css class to a certain controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My goal is simple, I just want to know the best approach on how to to do this.

Scenario

book_controller

```
def new
  @book = "book"
end
```

magazine_controller

```
def new
  @magazine = "magazine"
end
```

HTML

**application.html.erb**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <body of controller>
  </div>
</body>
```

**books/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>hello book</h1>
```

**magazines/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>hello magazine</h1>
```

**css**

```
.background-black {
    background: black
}
```

My goal is to add the background-black CSS class to the only `book_controller` for example

```
 <div class="container background-black">
```

But it will affect `magazine_controller` as well. What if I have 4 controllers that needed the black background and the rest don't need that class. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

The best ways to achieve your goal is to use [Controller Specific Assets](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets) as recommended in Rails asset pipeline docs ( you can find some implementation details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15192887/11533253)), but as you said what you want to do is simple so you can simply use erb syntax to dynamically control the value of the class attribute by calling a variable called *controller* populated by rails and containing information about the controller who render the view like the name of the controller.

```
<div class="container <%= controller.controller_name == 'book' ? 'background-black' : '' %>">
```

If you have 4 controllers that needed the black background you can use erb too.

```
 <div class="container <%= ['book','magazine','user', 'newspaper'].grep(/#{controller.controller_name}/).empty? ? '' : 'background-black' %>">
```

The answer mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22915786/11533253) use the same approch but have the advantage of  helping you keep your css code clean and readable.
Hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

First, You should delete some codes that `//= require_tree in application.css`,

Then  `<% self_css_path = "/assets/"+controller.controller_name  %> <%= stylesheet_link_tag self_css_path, :media => "all" %>` in application.html.erb