# How do you package assets for angularjs resusable components?

Tags: angularjs, sass, web-component

I'm currently working on an angularjs project and trying to build reuseable components - heavily inspired by [this article](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-bower.html) (which also spawned the [angular component spec](https://github.com/angular/angular-component-spec)).

I'm wondering how I should go about packaging images/stylesheets that I want to include in the components?

Some things I want:

- [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) styles
- A place to store images inside the component directory, and a way to reference them in stylesheets
- Override-able styles in application using components

---

Currently my thinking is:

Create the component in my bower components directory (`app/public/components`), so I have

```
app
  |-- public
    |-- components
      |-- prefix-component-name
        |-- assets
          |-- img
            |-- ...
        |-- views
          |-- templates
          |-- sass
            |-- styles.scss   <-- Component styles
    |-- img
    |-- css
    |-- js
    index.html
  |-- views
    |-- sass
      |-- application.scss      <-- Application styles
```

The application.scss would import the styles of the components with something like

```
@import "../../public/components/prefix-component-name/views/sass/styles";
```

Things I'm not sure about:

- How should I reference images - what if the path changes for the application developer? Create a sass variable for that path in the component?
- How would I override variables in sass files in the application? Do I want the application developer to do that? It seems if you override a variable in sass it propagates downwards from where it changes, so the application can only change it for itself.
- Can you pass paths to a sass file when you import?

---

My use case is specific to angularjs, but I'm sure the same issues apply to [W3C web components](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/), and libraries like [polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) and [mozilla brick](http://mozilla.github.io/brick/).

Any ideas?

Edit: `views` folder is same level as `assets`

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue by creating closed components.

### My approach

In the following example [sass-bootstrap](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) is used for demonstration purposes including your own *prefix-component-name*.

First its a good approach to use the assets folder to store all separated assets from the views.
I would also prefer to use kind of a `vendor.scss` in your stylesheets (SASS) to have a
separated file for something like the import path (you will come to limits with variables: [sass/compass import variable issue](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/49)).

**directory structure**

```
app
  |-- public
    |-- components
       |-- prefix-component-name
          |-- assets
            |-- sass
               |-- styles.scss
            |-- img
            |-- ...
          |-- views
            |-- index.html
            |-- ...
      |-- bootstrap-sass
        |-- vendor
          |-- assets
            |-- stylesheets // https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets
               |-- bootstrap
               |-- bootstrap.scss
        |-- ...
    |-- img
    |-- css
    |-- js
    index.html
  |-- views
    |-- sass
      |-- vendors.scss
      |-- application.scss
```

**vendor.scss**

`@import '../../public/components/bootstrap-sass/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss';
@import '../../public/components/prefix-component-name/assets/sass/styles.scss';`

Sadly [wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4778627/237209) a currently not supported.

### Your questions

1. My preference to use separate all assets made it easy to reference inside your stylesheets to images relatively to the component.
2. I didn't clearly got your question, but i guess the `vendors.scss` solves the storing of variables for paths.
3. Yes it gets in inherently. When you firstly import the `vendors.scss` in the `applicaion.scss` and you defined a variable in there you have it also available in `application.scss`.