# How to import directory in libsass

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, laravel-elixir, libsass

I am trying to import several `SCSS` files(page1.scss, page2.scss and ..) in my `app.scss` but I haven't found any solution(plugin and etc).

[image]

I saw [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778627/is-it-possible-to-import-a-whole-directory-in-sass-using-import) but they are for Ruby on Rails not libsass. I am using:

Gulp,

Gulp-sass,

Libsass and

Laravel Elixir

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Long answer short:

As you can find in this [issue](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/156#issuecomment-52234248) in the official libsass project github, [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) are not part of SASS specification, so there are no plans to support them in libsass.

### why?

The main concern about implementing this feature is related with the order importing the files. In first place, AFAIK there isn't a standard way on how reading stream files behave in different *OSs* (linux, mac os x, windows) or *filesystems* (reiserfs, ext3, ntfs, fat32, etc.), what leads to a unpredictable ordering while importing the files.

Anyway, even if there will be some sort of cross-platform standard support to read files from every filesystem and you are sure you are always gonna get the files in the same order. Which order should it be?.

### if you still need/want it:

Still there are some *hack-y* ways you can achieve this behaviour but I will strongly recommend to avoid them and follow the *official recommendations*.

There is a ruby gem: [sass-globbing](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing). But it doesn't works with gulp/libsass because of the different way they handle files streams. Inspired on this ruby-gem there is [gulp-css-globbing](https://github.com/jsahlen/gulp-css-globbing). It looks like this project is a bit outdated, but you can use it on your own risk.
And in this blog post: [Sass Directory Imports With Gulp](http://nateeagle.com/2014/05/22/sass-directory-imports-with-gulp/), you can find another solution that involve *automatically* creating a file per folder that imports all files inside. A bit convoluted for my taste but it will work if you really need this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.