# Shorter way to import with Scss/Sass

Tags: import, sass

I use Scss ([gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)) and it's a long list of includes that looks kind of like this:

```
@import '../../snippets/menu/menu.scss';
@import '../../snippets/footer/footer.scss';
@import '../../snippets/hero/hero.scss';
```

From this I can see a pattern. My question is if there is a nice way to make it simpler to write. Maybe something like this?

```
import('menu');
import('footer');
import('hero');
```

The output for scss should still be like the first snippet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to import a whole directory in sass using @import?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778627/is-it-possible-to-import-a-whole-directory-in-sass-using-import)

Comment: @hardcodepunk I'm using gulp-sass, forgot to mention that. Your suggestion does only support Rails. But else a nice solution.

Comment: @hardcodepunk NOT duplicate by the way... "This feature will never be part of Sass. One major reason is import order."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pushed in the right direction in the comments and the solution was a bit different than I expected. Now I use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-glob

**I allows for syntax like this:**

```
@import '../../snippets/**/*';
```