# Is there a way to import all partial files in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I would like to know if it's possible to write just a name of a folder and every file inside would be automatically imported?

For example, I have a `main.scss` which contains only imports

```
@import "components/forms";
@import "components/header";
@import 'components/intro';
```

and I would like to just write

```
@import "components/**/*";
```

So every file inside `components` will be imported as above.

Comment: ["Is It Possible To Import A Whole Directory In Sass Using Import"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778627/is-it-possible-to-import-a-whole-directory-in-sass-using-import)

Comment: Check out the the [sass-globbing gem](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing)

Comment: @SteveVentimiglia oh god thanks, I didn't find it. Sorry for duplicate post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can use `sass-globbing`. It lets me import directories or whole directory trees with a single @import statement:

```
// import a directory's contents
@import 'dir/*';

// recursively import a directory's contents and any sub-directories:
@import 'dir/**/*';
```

I’ll install it from the command line

```
gem install sass-globbing
```

more [here on Github plugin homepage](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing).