# Folder importing in SCSS

Tags: import, sass, node-modules

Say for example. Need to import a folder where all your scss partials in there. My query is how will I import the entire directory.

@import'layout/*.*'; Is this a right way or Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to import a whole directory in sass using @import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778627/is-it-possible-to-import-a-whole-directory-in-sass-using-import)

Answer (score 2):

You can't import a folder SCSS you have to import each file

```
// Modules and Variables
@import "/base";

// Partials
@import "/reset";
@import "/typography";
@import "/buttons";
@import "/figures";
@import "/grids";
// ...

// Third-party
@import "vendor/colorpicker";
@import "vendor/jquery.ui.core";
```

Also you can import one file that has already imported everything in the folder. This way you can choose not to import some files.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN import all partials within a given directory IF you're either using Ruby-on-Rails or using gulp (from my knowledge). In Gulp there is a plugin called `gulp-sass-glob` that will enable this to work. It's how I personally do my own imports.

Comment: there is also a gem install sass-globbing which enables you to use * Wildcards.
you do this like `@import "layout/*"` or `@import "layout/**/*"` to include subdirectories.
On Windows you have to us `@import "layout**/**"` and I did not find a way to include subdirectories till now.